# Updating a column values randomly in CSV using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I need to update a column in CSV with some incremental value. So for example:

```
Name, Surname, Reference
Joe, Joey, aaa
Jane, Doe, aab
```

needs to be converted to:

```
Name, Surname, Reference
Joe, Joey, ABC13842783
Jane, Doe, ABC24862121
```

Now how do I save the value of the printf in the 3rd column and save it back to the file

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {
        FS=","
    }
    {
        printf("ABC~%08d\n", rand()*10000000) 
    }
' Users.csv
```

Can you please help?

Comment: for incremental numbering a while read loop is beginners friendly. column can be extracted with grep or cut and written into new file, or try with sed capturing groups on file directly. awk is probably best tool but i can't help with

Comment: @Cyrus thank you for the guidance. My attempt was so pathetic I thought I better leave it out. Also alecxs, thank you, since I want to update all the rows and I am happy to use random, I may not have to use loops. I updated my question with this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v prefix="ABC" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} NR>1{$3=prefix NR-1} {print}' file
```

With your update:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} NR>1{$3=sprintf("ABC%08d", rand()*10000000)} {print}' file
```

Output:

```
Name, Surname, Reference
Joe, Joey, ABC09240458
Jane, Doe, ABC05939086
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Also worth noting that `rand()` in `awk` will generate the same random sequence of numbers each time a script is run unless `srand()` is called with a different seed. Perhaps `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "; srand()} ...`